# Show that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

> **Question:** Let rule $\varphi \colon (S^1 \times I)/(S^1 \times \{0\}) \rightarrow D^2$ defined by $\varphi([(z,t)]) = tz$ for all $[(z,t)] \in (S^1 \times I)/(S^1 \times \{0\})$. Show that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism.

Could you give me some hints to solve this problem. Thank all!

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @AsuraPath To show that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism we have to check three conditions: $\varphi$ is a bijection, $\varphi$ is continuous, $\varphi^{-1}$ is continuous. But I don't know hơ to check that.

Comment: what are $I$ and $D$ here? Also, does $S^1$ means unit circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of category theory,  this is the cone functor, $C(X)$, with $X=S^1\in \bf{Top}$, and $\varphi=C(id)$.

Think of polar coordinates.   Every point in the disk, other than the origin,  has a unique representation as $(\theta, r), \,\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$.  The origin,  on the other hand,  can be represented by $(\theta,0)$, for any $\theta$.  That's the reason for moding out by $S^1×\{0\}$, which identifies it to a point.

For injectivity,  let $t_1z_1=t_2z_2$, for $t_1,t_2\in I$ and $z_1,z_2\in S^1$.  Then $t_1=t_2$ and $z_1=z_2$.

For surjectivity, given $x\in D^2$, $x=tz=\varphi (z,t)$ for some $t\in I$ and $z\in S^1$.  This is basically just uniqueness of the polar form, $re^{i\theta}$.

For continuity,  let $(z,t)\to (z_0,t_0)$.  Then $\varphi (z,t)=zt\to t_0z_0=\varphi (z_0,t_0)$.  After all, it's the product of continuous functions, the projections onto each coordinate.

Similarly the inverse is continuous.

(So, you have a cylinder ($S^1×I$), and when you take the quotient by $S^1×\{0\}$, you identify one end to a point.  This gives you a cone.  But a cone is clearly homeomorphic to a disk.)

Comment: Note this is a quotient of a compact space so is compact. This implies that a bijective continuous map is a homeomorphism since the codomain is Hausdorff.

Comment: Indeed.   Thanks for that @Connor.